# "is not a function" jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I have a little problem with jQuery. I just want to remove and add class on my "li" but it said to me "is not a function". Here my code :

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var title = $('title')
    var nav = $('.nav-a')

    for ($i = 0 ; $i<nav.length ; $i++)
    {
       if (title[0].text === nav[$i].text){
        var newTitle = title[0].text
        var newNav = nav[$i].text
        var navI = nav[$i].parentElement
        console.log(newTitle)
        console.log(newNav)
        console.log(navI)

        nav.parent().removeClass('menu-active')
        navI.addClass('menu-active')
       }
    }
  })
```

In console I have : Uncaught TypeError: navI.addClass is not a function

Comment: `navI` is DOM and not jQuery... Some reason you are mixing jQuery and DOM.

Comment: Also matching on text is horrible. You should have some kind of matching attribute to match elements to each other. Now when you decide to change the text for one element it brakes your code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're calling native Element object methods on jQuery objects and vice versa.

To fix this stick with one or the other. As such, here's a simplified jQuery example, which uses `filter()` to match elements by their text instead of an explicit loop.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var title = $('title').text();
  var nav = $('.nav-a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() === title;
  }).parent().addClass('menu-active'); 
})
```